# AWS architecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

We have around 10 different AWS accounts, I'm working on building an application internally for viewing the activity on these accounts.The activity consist of different nodes launched terminated , including usage and costs related to each account.This I'm planning to show it on internal portal.
The challenge here is I need to store and show whatever data I get from aws-sdk's.
I need some suggestions on architecture this kind of a platform, I'd want data as realtime as possible.

Any suggestions would be great

Answer (score 4):

I think your best choice for the architecture is: none. And the reason is: you don't need it. Use CloudTrail for reporting the activities, and Billing for the costs. AWS now supports federated account, and with IAM you can easily configure a role who can just see that data for all the accounts.

Comment: Not sure if you understood my question correctly, we have bunch of nodes under each account.By having multiple accounts it is difficult to track the node.I already made wrote an application which gathers data on daily basis stores all aws infrastructure  data in a mysql database. The same data what you see under 10 aws accounts I show it on one application. The only difference is I sort the data based on team,products.Now I'd like to make it more realtime instead of daily basis.

Comment: What do you mean by "track the node"?

Comment: By having realtime data stored , at any given time I can track how many nodes were terminated,stopped or launched on a given day .When I say track node I meant infrastructure usage like ELB,EC2,RDS etc. Again I'm not looking for metrics.Just the list of infrastructures being used.I'm able to get this data using aws-sdk but, I'd like to store them and also show them on application in realtime.For example if a user launches an EC2 node or RDS I'd like to get that infrastructure details and show it on my in house application. The lag should not be more that 30 to 60 min

Comment: I'm still convinced that CloudTrail is what you need. Also: it would provide many others features (like realtime notifications), like all the other AWS services will be enriched as the time pass, you don't have to maintain the solution, etc... As said, it can work on multiple accounts. I really can't see any reason to reimplement it with a custom solution.

Comment: @MatteoSp, CloudTrail provides only the raw data.  There still has to be an "architecture" to ingest, interpret, structure, store, index, retrieve, and present the data.

Comment: Transforming and presenting is architecture? Is so, I'm a nuclear engineer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [traildash](https://github.com/AppliedTrust/traildash). This is an all in one dashboard for cloudtrail. The other comments are 100% correct, AWS provides most of this already, Traildash simply wraps a nice GUI on it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this question has been addressed, but fwiw here is my take.

If I got it right, this question is about how to monitor the aws resources(ec2, s3, and etc) across multiple accounts regularly and automatically.

Programmatically I'd suggest the star-topology that having a service account, and accessing all other accounts through it by assuming roles. In this way we do not need to keep aws accessKey/secretKey for those accounts locally, thus having better security.

The implementation has to do with a new role/policy created in the service account which specifies a list of accountId/role that it can assume, and a new role/policy created in each of other accounts which allows read-access to its own resource.

For your reference, here is an example of policy to access ec2 instances:

service account policy:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
   {
   "Sid": "",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
   "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID-A:role/ROLE-A",
          "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID-B:role/ROLE-B”,
          "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID-C:role/ROLE-C”,
          "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID-D:role/ROLE-D”,
          "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID-E:role/ROLE-E”,
   ]
   },
   "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
   }
   ]
}
```

normal account policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": “ec2:DescribeInstances",
    "Resource": “arn:aws:ec2:Account-ID-A:instance/*"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS cloud trail is a best option for your requirement. Store all cloud trail logs on S3 and fetch it to where you want to show them.
You can use Graylog like log aggregation tools to have grate user experience and various dashboards based on your requirements.

Hope this helps...

Thanks
Kiran